# How to let a C++ application to receive data from PHP?

Tags: php, c++, xml

I have developed an application on C++. And I would like to connect my website to the C++ software.

I want the website to send a string or an image to the C++ application; then after the C++ receives the string/image, it will process it and return the output back to the website.

My question is how to let the website (which is hosted on my local server) to send a direct message to the C++ application which is also hosted on my PC.

Comment: This seems like an overly broad question with many possible answers. What problem are you trying to solve by serializing a string or image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System-independent interprocess-communication can be implemented using sockets. Listen for clients in your C++ application and connect to it using [PHPs socket API](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php).

Answer (score 1):

An option could be to develop, in your C++ program, a small HTTP server.
Take a look at [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html) in HTTP section.

Answer (score 1):

if this is on one single windows machine then named pipes might be useful for you
. Named pipes are good solution if the C++ application is located in the same physical server as the server application. In that case the OS would be just moving memory between processes for you so it could be very quick.
[look here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365781%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

if you can get your app to act as a web server or as a CGI app. then all you need to do is:

```
  file_get_contents('http://localhost/path/to/c/exe?parameter=param'); 
  //You could use curl as well, I used file_get_contents for simplicity
```

You could also use sockets.

A third option would be executing your c++ exe from php with backticks:

```
$result=`myapp.exe`;
```

Comment: This is exactly the opposite of what the OP wants. He wants to send data from PHP app to C++ app.

Comment: hum, I guess I misread. I guess in that case he can either use a system call to execute php: system('php phpfile.php'); . Technically, he can also use sockets but that would complicate the call a bit

Comment: by the way, after re-reading, the op seems to want it both ways so it could be a hybrid of both I guess.